# List of all NANP area codes and central office / exchanges and their geographic location?

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for some open data that would list every area code in the NANP.  And all the 3-digit exchanges that exist for that area code.  And what geolocation they relate to.

I have found some of this data in a smattering of Wikipedia pages, for example:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_North_American_Numbering_Plan_area_codes
Which lists all the area codes, and links out to detailed pages about each area code, such as:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_codes_416,_647,_and_437

And while I could likely build a scraper to get some of this data collected, there are other Area codes on Wikipedia that do not list the exchanges / central office codes.
For example:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_codes_201_and_551

And also there is absolutely no consistency between the individual pages, so building the scraper is going to be a huge task.

There used to be a website called areacodedownload.com that had some of this content, it can still be seen at archive.org
http://web.archive.org/web/20080302180916/http://www.areacodedownload.com/201/index.html

Does anyone know of any open data source for what I am looking for?

Edit: Ok, I think I just found a resource that has pretty much what I want:
http://www.nationalnanpa.com/enas/coCodeReportUnsecured.do?reportType=7
But this only covers the USA, I need Canada as well.

Comment: how much of the data does areacodedownload on the wayback machine have?

Comment: Ahh good point i could probably just scrape that instead. i don't know why i didn't think of that.  I was somewhat hoping to find a resource that would have the whole thing as a CSV already, but maybe that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.nationalnanpa.com/nanp1/npa_report.csv with definitions found in http://www.nationalnanpa.com/area_codes/AreaCodeDatabaseDefinitions.xls

Look through nationalnanpa.com's sitemap has some valuable resources.

http://cnac.ca/data/COCodeStatus_ALL.zip gives you Canadian codes.